# Is there an uncountable family of "hereditarily unembeddable" continua?

Tags: gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, continuum-theory

Define a family $\{C_i\}_{i\in I}$ of continua, that is compact connected metrizable spaces, to be *hereditarily unembeddable* (a name I just made up) iff for all $i\neq j$ no nontrivial subcontinuum of $C_i$ embeds in $C_j$.

Is there an uncountable family of continua which is hereditarily unembeddable? Is there such a family made of planar continua?

Embarrassingly I can only construct such families with three (maybe four) elements!

Comment: I can see how to get a family with two (the arc and the pseudo-arc). How do you get three?

Comment: @JamesHanson There are hereditarily decomposable continua that contain no arcs (and of course no pseudoarcs either), such a continuum is constructed in Exercise 2.27 of Nadler's *Continuum Theory* (I wrote maybe four in the question because it is not clear to me whether the continuum constructed in 2.32 of the same book can be added to this family)

Comment: Consider so called Cook continuum:
A nondegenerate continuum $C$ is called a Cook continuum if every continuous mapping $f$ of a subcontinuum $K$ of $C$ into $C$ is either a constant mapping or identity embedding on $K$.

Using this single object (which can be constructed even in the plane), by considering disjoint subcontinua, you get a family with no nontrivial embeddings. Such a family can be easily made countable infinite using Boundary Bumping Theorem. At the moment, I dont see how to prove that there is such an uncountable family.

Comment: There is a nice construction of a Cook continuum in the book by Pultr and Trnkova: Combinatorial, algebraic and topological representations of groups, semigroups and categories, page 320. Perhaps using the additional properties an uncountable collection of disjoint nondegenerate continua can be constructed.